# ufw on new install of 19.10 blocking web

Tags: ufw

I re-installed 19.10 recently and am now setting up UFW. Using the same table as the previous installation I have no internet connection.

The settings :

```
 Status: active

 To                         Action      From
 --                         ------      ----
 22                         ALLOW       10.0.0.0/24               
 2314                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
 53                         ALLOW       10.0.0.0/24               
 111                        ALLOW       10.0.0.0/24               
 2049                       ALLOW       10.0.0.0/24               
 33333                      ALLOW       10.0.0.0/24               
 873                        ALLOW       10.0.0.0/24               
 80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
 443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
 2314 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
 80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
 443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: How do you know internet connection is not working? And what you show is incoming rules, not outgoing rules. They will **not** impact normal net use, and there's no reason to open for instance port 53, unless you're running a DNS server on your computer.

Comment: @user68186 Yes. I get internet with ufw disabled. And then lose it again when enabled. Toggles off and on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firewall default was set to `deny (outgoing)`. I remember that in previous versions the default at install was `allow (outgoing)`. A simple `ufw status` does not show that. By checking status with `verbose` however:

```
sudo ufw status verbose

Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), deny (outgoing), disabled (routed)
```

The fix is to

```
 sudo ufw default allow outgoing
```